# Is there a place for one more index processor?

Tags: indexing

> **(This is not a real question, it's rather a list of thoughts and ideas.)**

I'm not a serious TeXist, but this topic of index creation interests me a lot. As I like programming in Lua, I started to think if I could try an experiment or two to cover some topics in the indexing world. Let me think about it for a while. In this post/question, I'm trying to collect ideas which we are missing, could be improved or simply it would be nice to have them among out-of-the-box features.

This list might help programmers to actually program something new or me to get on the right track before I actually do some programming.

## What's ready for use? (TeX Live 2014, possibly next years too)

There are some tools and packages we use frequently for sorting and/or index creation:

- The [MakeIndex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeindex) index processor. There is a fine chapter in the [LaTeX Companion, 2nd ed.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201362996) about modifying styles.
- The [Xindy](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xindy) index processor.
- The [imakeidx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) package and some other packages, e.g. [splitindex](http://ctan.org/pkg/splitindex), [multind](http://ctan.org/pkg/multind).
- The [glossaries](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package.
- The [OPmac](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html) extended plainTeX macros (see `\makeindex`).
- The [biber](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber) tool (sorting only).
- The [ConTeXt](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/context) engine.

---

## What we may like to have at our disposal? (to be updated)

> **Support for more languages**

For [xindy](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/), I tried to prepare definition files for [Sanskrt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97444/indexing-through-texindy-in-imakeidx-with-custom-xdy-style-fails-to-produce-des) (transliteration scheme) and [Pāḷi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/xindy-how-to-add-new-letters-and-lettergroups-to-the-alphabet). But it's quite time consuming to set it up properly. It would be better to define just some letters, let's say in a Lua table. It would be also helpful to have an option to set up a language dialect.

> **Support for CJKV languages**

The support for CJKV and other exotic languages is weak in xindy. They are using radicals, number of strokes and even frequency of kanjis in Japanese (JLPT levels). It means that we must handle additional data sets, e.g. [Unicode Character Database; UCD](http://www.unicode.org/ucd/) or [Unihan Database](http://www.unicode.org/charts/unihan.html). I haven't checked out the new engines and tools in detail ([xepersian](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/xepersian), support for Japanese, Chinese, Korean etc.), I cannot say if the index creation is ready for TeX users.

> **Setting up a new set of sorting rules and letter groups**

One of the examples comes from the chemistry field and its Periodic Table of Elements. I believe we could find some examples in Astrophysics. It would be interesting to sort items by its colour (name, wave), but that's not a common task.

> **Two-way hyperlinks**

It would be great to have two-way hyperlinks coming to/from the index. I tried that once in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165579/index-that-picks-up-on-example-numbers-not-page-numbers). Sometimes we turn two-way hyperlinks on elsewhere, e.g. in the footnotes.

> **Mixing writing**

It might be possible to switch between transliteration schemes (like in XeLaTeX via map files) at the input/output side, or we could even mix them, e.g. sayōnara + さようなら which is the same index entry (romanized version, hiragana).

> **Index with different piece of information**

I've shown one of the approaches in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165579/index-that-picks-up-on-example-numbers-not-page-numbers), but it is far from user-friendly. Instead of page numbers, we might have other blocks, such as sections, numbers of line in the source code, numbers of the problem/solution, numbers of some examples, verse numbers, or own counter. There is an interesting [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31148/how-to-create-index-for-verses) dealing with adding a beginning of the verse to the index.

> **List of occurences**

Also a list of occurences of the index entries (and number of index entries in the group letter) should be easily available (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41140/symbol-index-sorted-by-occurrence)).

> **Support for indexing more languages in one index**

There is an open issue of [finderlist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174982/how-to-make-dictionary-finderlist-with-glossaries-or-index-packages), it might be useful not only for Pohnpeian + English. We should be able to change the order of languages of such a finderlist. There is one more interesting open issue: [Ancient Egyptian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46026/xindy-for-ancient-egyptian-transliteration), where could be even three different languages/sorting systems (pronunciation, transliteration, Unicode notation and translation).

> **Modifying rules**

I tried to correct [Icelandic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165273/texindy-sorting-icelandic) and [Vietnamese](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142345/sorting-vietnamese-utf8-index-with-make-rules-in-xindy-package) in Xindy, but it took a lot of time. In Czech, for instance, some people like to have letter groups as `A, B, C, Č, D, ..., S, Š, ... U, V, W, X, Y, Z`, but some people (due to lack of index entries) like to have `A, B, CČ, D, ..., SŠ, ..., U, V, W, XYZ`.

> **Testing files**

In addition to the previous item, it would be great to have some testing files per language. Or some examples of / links to already created documents with index. It's possible to find some books, but it requires a lot of researching for non-native speakers in that language. It remains me test cases in data analysis to measure efficiency of a new algorithm.

> **Sorting engine on, indexing engine off**

It would be nice to be able to switch between indexing and sorting engines. I tried to modify a [xindy style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173961/xindy-as-a-sorting-engine) once. Indexing processor might behave like a sorting engine upon request.

> **Sorting engine off, indexing engine on**

I used a trick with [adding numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/makeindex-without-sorting) before an index term. It works, but I wouldn't recommend it for general use. It might be interesting to get an index within some group without sorting index entries within the letter/page group (it equals to an appearance in text, or sorting by page numbers without additional sorting key).

> **Handling numbers**

Xindy is handling arabic and roman (I'm not 100% sure here) numbers well, see e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/index-sorting-where-numbers-are-indexed). There should be an addition to hexadecimal numbers. It could be solved with regular expressions in Lua. We may like to switch the output of the numbers (Western or Eastern Arabic, Roman, Urdu variant, Bengali, Indian numbers, ...).

> **Easy setting of the tags at the output side**

We could be able to easily set up all tags used in the index. We could be able to limit number of elements, e.g. to see only the first element (first occurence of the index entry / definition / abbreviation). It's been discussed at TeX.SX.

> **Automatic repetion of the group letter**

Once we have an index with more columns/pages, it would be nice to have group letters at the beginning of each column/page automatically repeated.

> **Adding text before and after index**

We can do a lot of formatting at a TeX level, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56826/xindy-encapsulations-for-index), but there should be an easier way how to add information to the index. Moreover, we should be able to hyperlink whole index entry (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225093/imakeidx-hyperlink-both-the-index-title-and-the-page-number)).

> **Creating more indices**

We can do that easily with the help of the [imakeidx](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) package, see [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/indexing-all-initial-and-non-initial-words). We may like to have minindices (per chapter, section, page number), something similar to the [minitoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package for Mini Table of Contents handling.

> **Index creation without TeXing**

There are certain situations where we might not even need TeX at all. Lua could parse input TeX files. Michal.h21 showed one of the situations, [indexing against keyword file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136109/automated-indexing-against-keyword-file), but that's a rare task.

---

## Where the TeX world stands now?

> **Xindy**

A new language can be set via [xindy-make-rules](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xindy/files/xindy-make-rules/0.2/) for [Xindy](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/). The structure of data looks like this. We use or we leave empty so-called slots (arrays in arrays in an array).

```
$language = "Czech";
$prefix = "cs";
$script = "latin";

$alphabet = [
['A',    ['a','A'], ['á','Á'],['ä','Ä']],
                   [], # a with breve (romanian)
                   [], # a with circumflex (romanian)
                   [], # a with ogonek (polish)
['B',    ['b','B']],
                   [], # b with hook (hausa)

[... omitted...]         

['Z',    ['z','Z']],
                   [], # zh (albanian)
                   [], # zs (hungarian)
['Ž',    ['ž','Ž']],
                   [], # z with acute (lower sorbian, polish)
                   [], # z with dot above (polish)
];

$ligatures = [
[['ß'], 'after', [['s','s']]],
];

@special = ('?', '!', '.', 'letters', '-', '\'');

$sortcase = "Aa";
#$sortcase = "aA";

do 'make-rules.pl';
```

> **TECkit**

[TECkit](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?cat_id=TECkit) offers fast and flexible way for transliteration schemes, but it can be used only in XeTeX on-the-fly.

> **LuaTeX and ConTeXt**

Hans Hagen and comp. are developing tools very fast (ConTeXt, LuaTeX). For instance, in the `/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/sort-lan.lua` file, we can find sorting rules for the Czech language:

```
[... omitted ...]
definitions["cz"] = {
    replacements = {
        { "ch", ch }, { "Ch", ch }, { "CH", ch }
    },
    entries = {
        ["a"] = "a", ["á"] = "a", ["b"] = "b", ["c"] = "c",  ["č"] = "č",
        ["d"] = "d", ["ď"] = "d", ["e"] = "e", ["é"] = "e",  ["ě"] = "e",
        ["f"] = "f", ["g"] = "g", ["h"] = "h", [ch]  = "ch", ["i"] = "i",
        ["í"] = "i", ["j"] = "j", ["k"] = "k", ["l"] = "l",  ["m"] = "m",
        ["n"] = "n", ["ň"] = "n", ["o"] = "o", ["ó"] = "o",  ["p"] = "p",
        ["q"] = "q", ["r"] = "r", ["ř"] = "ř", ["s"] = "s",  ["š"] = "š",
        ["t"] = "t", ["ť"] = "t", ["u"] = "u", ["ú"] = "u",  ["ů"] = "u",
        ["v"] = "v", ["w"] = "w", ["x"] = "x", ["y"] = "y",  ["ý"] = "y",
        ["z"] = "z", ["ž"] = "ž",
    },
    orders = {
        "a", "á", "b", "c", "č", "d", "ď", "e", "é", "ě",
        "f", "g", "h", ch,  "i", "í", "j", "k", "l", "m",
        "n", "ň", "o", "ó", "p", "q", "r", "ř", "s", "š",
        "t", "ť", "u", "ú",  "ů", "v", "w", "x",  "y", "ý",
        "z", "ž",
    },
    upper = {
        ch = CH,
    },
    lower = {
        CH = ch,
    }
}

definitions["cs"] = { parent = "cz" }
[... omitted ...]
```

It's a nice way of handling Lua tables, but I feel it could be simplified for a regular user for setting up own sorting/indexing rules.

---

## CLDR: A way to go?

> **First look at the CLDR data**

I like an approach by the Unicode Consortium (it's similar, maybe even related, to the [biber](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/biber) tool for sorting bibliography entries), they are providing so called [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/index) data (Unicode Common Locale Data Repository; I've found this project just recently), which includes data for index creation. Let me show you an example for the Czech language (after downloading and unzipping the `core.zip` file, http://unicode.org/Public/cldr/27/). The rules are written in the `/code/common/main/` folder in the `cs.xml` file.

```
  [... omitted ...]
  <characters>
      <exemplarCharacters>[a á b c č d ď e é ě f g h {ch} i í j k l m n ň o ó p q r ř s š t ť u ú ů v w x y ý z ž]</exemplarCharacters>
      <exemplarCharacters type="auxiliary">[à ă â å ä ã ā æ ç è ĕ ê ë ē ì ĭ î ï ī ľ ł ñ ò ŏ ô ö ø ō œ ŕ ù ŭ û ü ū ÿ]</exemplarCharacters>
      <exemplarCharacters type="index" draft="contributed">[A B C Č D E F G H {CH} I J K L M N O P Q R Ř S Š T U V W X Y Z Ž]</exemplarCharacters>
      <exemplarCharacters type="punctuation">[\- ‐ – , ; \: ! ? . … ‘ ‚ “ „ ( ) \[ \] § @ * / \&amp;]</exemplarCharacters>
  [... omitted ...]
```

If we could parse this data (see this webpage about [LDML](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/); the Unicode Locale Data Markup Language), rules for a new language (Czech one in this example) can be set up. It's covering many languages and dialects, but e.g. [Pohnpeian language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohnpeian_language) is not covered, yet. Therefore I think, there still should be an easy way how to define a new language even with this data available.

There is probably a lot of tools to parse and preprocess these files, let me mention [cldr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cldr) from the JavaScript world.

It's hard to say if [biber](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/biber) can be used for sorting in index creation, even if it could, it isn't handling typical issues of the index creation.

> **Notes about Sinhala and Tamil**

Some years ago, Zdeněk Wagner from Prague, showed me his experiment in Devanāgarī, but it isn't included among official Xindy files, yet. Zdeněk told me his files are not completely ready to be published. So support for Brāhmī scripts is likely still weak.

One day, I would like to see sorted lists / indices e.g. in [Pāḷi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali), preferably in [Sinhala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhalese_language) and [Tamil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_language) not mentioning Japanese, Chinese, Korean and many more.

It looks it might be possible as CLDR contains files `si.xml` ([ISO 639-1](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/codes.asp?order=639_1&letter=s); Sinhala) and `ta.xml` ([ISO 639-1](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/codes.asp?order=639_1&letter=t); Tamil). [Allkeys](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/latest/allkeys.txt) from Unicode might provide some help in certain languages/situations.

It looks that difficult part in programming is handling complex ligatures in those Eastern languages (next to handling radicals and number of strokes; that's another big issue). This is a portion of the table scheme a colleague of mine, Jan Kučera from Prague, sent me for Tamil. After we type a character followed by one of the MarkPlaceholders we are getting a ligature. That's a general idea, he has probably implemented it somewhere.

```
"", "^");
"அ", "a");
"ஆ", "ā", "A", "aa");
"இ", "i");
"ஈ", "ī", "I", "ee");
"உ", "u");
"ஊ", "ū", "U", "oo");
"எ", "e");
"ஏ", "ē", "E");
"ஐ", "ai");
"ஒ", "o");
"ஓ", "ō", "O");
"ஔ", "au", "ou", "ow");
"ஃ", "ḵ", "H", "q");
"க" + MarkPlaceholder, "k", "K", "kh", "G", "gh");
"ங" + MarkPlaceholder, "ṅ", "ng", "~g", "g"); // g is க in Baraha
"ச" + MarkPlaceholder, "c", "s", "ch", "C", "Ch");
"ஞ" + MarkPlaceholder, "ñ", "n^", "ny", "NY", "jn", "~j", "nJ"); // ந can be n^ in Madurai
"ட" + MarkPlaceholder, "ṭ", "T", "Th", "d", "D", "Dh"); // d is த in Baraha
"ண" + MarkPlaceholder, "ṇ", "N");
"த" + MarkPlaceholder, "t", "th", "dh");
"ந" + MarkPlaceholder, "n", "~n", "nN"); // n is ன in Baraha
"ப" + MarkPlaceholder, "p", "P", "ph", "b", "B", "bh");
"ம" + MarkPlaceholder, "m", "M");
"ய" + MarkPlaceholder, "y", "Y");
"ர" + MarkPlaceholder, "r");
"ல" + MarkPlaceholder, "l");
"வ" + MarkPlaceholder, "v", "w");
"ழ" + MarkPlaceholder, "z", "zh", "Lx");
"ள" + MarkPlaceholder, "ḷ", "L");
"ற" + MarkPlaceholder, "ṟ", "R", "rx");
"ன" + MarkPlaceholder, "ṉ", "_n", "n2");
"ஜ" + MarkPlaceholder, "j", "jh", "J");
"ஶ" + MarkPlaceholder, "ś");
"ஷ" + MarkPlaceholder, "ṣ", "sh"); // sh is ஶ in Baraha
"ஸ" + MarkPlaceholder, "S"); 
"ஹ" + MarkPlaceholder, "h", "~h");

"", "a", "^");
"ா", "ā", "A", "aa");
"ி", "i");
"ீ", "ī", "I", "ee");
"ு", "u");
"ூ", "ū", "U", "oo");
"ெ", "e");
"ே", "ē", "E");
"ை", "ai");
"ொ", "o");
"ோ", "ō", "O");
"ௌ", "au", "ou", "ow");
```

> **A closing note about Kana**

Once, I tried to prepare a style for Xindy for Kana (Hiragana and Katakana), it worked, but the core which is to be processed are the kanjis. I would like to finish my notes with a preview of this Xindy [experiment](http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/kana-v1.rar) from 2010. I believe that this is not the easiest way how to set up and maintain definition files for index generation. These files are not ready for production, it's highly unlikely to have an index of just Kana. In case we have a couple of terms in Kana, we would probably use `\index{sayounara@さようなら}` in our document.

Thus, I was thinking in this post, if I(we) could do something about that to improve the current state in the world of indexing.

[image: Kana example]

Comment: entirely missing from this list is how to create an index of notation in a reasonably sane way.  the only really logical ones i have ever seen were hand-tuned, either by assigning sort keys individually, or created entirely by hand using `\label` and `\ref` to apply page numbers (but that means multiple `\label`s for any term that is to be "indexed" more than once).  since ordering is, to a great extent, subjective, i don't see an easy solution to this.

Comment: one of my "projects for retirement" is to index *tugboat*.  for that, the sorting of items isn't a problem (just drudgery compiling the data), but the representation of where they appear is a nightmare: volume + issue (not always needed) + page(s).  already mentioned here under "Index with different piece of information", just with slightly different content.

Comment: @Malipivo I don't understand why do you miss the indexing plus sorting directly by TeX macros (in OPmac) in your list. You are from Czech republics and you do know OPmac. Why the `\makeindex` from this package is missing here?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: For a customer I created some years ago a xindy style and some commands for a yearly index of a journal which appeared every month. He wanted a system like "I/2013_{715}:1,5" (month/year_{issueNr}:page,page). I don't know if someone actually can find an item with such a reference ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- xindy is indeed the most promising option we've got now; i'm resigned to the possibility that i may be the only person to actually *use* the resulting index.  at least you've confirmed for me that it *can* be done.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for your feedback! I'll think about index of notation, these days I think more in terms of parsing CLDR as a starting point or solving that English+Pohnpeian finderlist. I tried to solve that Ancient Egyptian, but Xindy is not suitable for that. To TUGboat, yes, it can be done, in Xindy, you can define a new location class (http://xindy.sourceforge.net/doc/tutorial-3.html). It would be nice if you could open a new question providing some data and requested output(s). :-) E.g. if year, issue and page should be clickable independently, that would be a challenge.

Comment: for some Lua exercises, take a look at https://github.com/michal-h21/prirustak/blob/master/sort.lua for sorting Lua tables in Czech (other languages can be added easily) and https://github.com/michal-h21/uninormalize for unicode normalization

Comment: The first step is the CLDR data (in json rather than xml), it is the way to go and to also harvest efforts from other communities and use Lua not xindy!

Comment: Regarding `glossaries`, in addition to using `makeindex` or `xindy` or TeX to do the sorting and location list collation, there's [`bib2gls`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/bib2gls/) (currently still under development) that works with `glossaries-extra` that can be used to perform the indexing. With Java 8, it can use the CLDR for language-based sorting. (It can also sort in other ways, such as numerically or in order of use.)

Comment: I don't know if you've already come across it, but I wrote an article in TUGboat on testing indexing methods (Volume 38, Number 3, 2017 "Testing indexes: testidx.sty").

Answer (score 3):

> Testing files

The [`testidx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/testidx) package is designed for testing indexing. It covers the Basic Latin set and some extended characters common in some European languages, but it's designed to be extendible. A simple test document:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{testidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\testidx

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This creates a test document with a seven page index that contains a symbols group, a number group, and the 26 Basic Latin letter groups A, …, Z.

Some extra terms are available if the T1 font encoding is used (which provides `\dh` etc):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{testidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\testidx

\printindex
\end{document}
```

There are two UTF-8 modes available with `inputenc`:

- Sanitize: the sort value is first sanitized before being passed to `\index` to prevent the active characters from being expanded as they are written to the indexing file. This mode is designed to test the indexing application's ability to sort UTF-8 characters.
- No sanitize: the sort value isn't sanitized before being passed to `\index`. How the UTF-8 characters are written to the indexing file depends on the definition of `\index`. The standard definition results in expansion.

Example (the default `sanitize` mode):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{testidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\testidx

\printindex
\end{document}
```

For example, the `.idx` file contains:

```
\indexentry{élite}{4}
```

This will cause a problem for `makeindex`, which doesn't support UTF-8, but it can be used to test `xindy`.

Example (`nosanitize` mode):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[nosanitize]{testidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\testidx

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The `.idx` file now contains:

```
\indexentry{\IeC {\'e}lite}{4}
```

With XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX the result is the same in both modes as the UTF-8 characters aren't active and so don't expand.

By default, the terms are variously indexed without an encap or with one of three test encaps. The dummy text is intentionally designed to trigger an encap clash. If you don't need to test for this you can switch it off with `notestencaps`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[notestencaps]{testidx}

\makeindex[program=texindy,options={-C utf8 -L icelandic}]

\begin{document}
\testidx

\printindex
\end{document}
```

In this case, the index contains a default group (which includes symbols, numbers, and the letters that don't occur in the Icelandic alphabetic rule: Ć, Ł, Ś and Ż), and the letter groups A, …, D, ð, E, …, Z, Þ, Æ, Ö and Å.

The index additionally includes some terms that start with a digraph (such as dd, dz, ff, ij, ll, ly, ng, th) as well as a trigraph (dzs) to allow for testing the indexing application's ability to deal with these.

By default, symbols are indexed in the form

```
\index{>alpha@$\alpha$}
```

or

```
\index{<tstidxmarker@\csname tstidxmarker\endcsname \space (\tstidxcsfmt {tstidxmarker})}
```

or

```
\index{E@$E$}
```

to represent different ways of indexing symbols. The `<` and `>` prefixes allow different types of symbols to be grouped together but you can omit this prefix with the `noprefix` option.

There's also a supplementary package `testidx-glossaries` that uses the `glossaries` package interface instead of `\index`.

Additional test paragraphs can be added using `\tstidxnewblock`. The starred form requires a control sequence for the first argument that can be used to save the block number if it needs to be referenced in another block (`\label`/`\ref` aren't used as the reference is typically used as an instruction to the user and it can't be resolved if required block is omitted.) For example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[notestencaps]{testidx}

\makeindex[program=texindy,options={-C utf8 -L general}]

\tstidxnewblock*{\mystartblock}{The \tstidxopenword{cat} sat
on the \tstidxword{mat}. (This block requires block~\myendblock\
to close a range.)}

\tstidxnewblock{O gato \tstidxutfword{engra\c{c}ado}[engracado]{engraçado}
perseguiu o papagaio bobo.}

\tstidxnewblock*{\myendblock}{The \tstidxcloseword{cat} made friends
with the parrot. (This block requires block~\mystartblock.)}

\begin{document}
\testidx

\printindex
\end{document}
```

These new block definitions can go in a package that automatically loads `testidx`.

> CLDR: A way to go?

There's now a new indexing alternative [`bib2gls`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) but it requires [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra). Instead of using `\index`, terms are defined in `.bib` files. Since `bib2gls` is a Java application, if you have at least Java 8 then there you can use the CLDR as the locale provider. With Java 8, this requires `-Djava.locale.providers=CLDR,JRE,SP` (which is included in the bash script distributed with `bib2gls`). You may prefer a different order, for example `-Djava.locale.providers=CLDR,SP,JRE`. By placing `CLDR` first in the list, it's given the highest priority. If the locale isn't supported by the CLDR, then the next provider is checked. (I think Java 9 supports the CLDR by default.)

Here's a simple `.bib` file (called, say, `entries.bib`):

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@index{animal}
@index{duck,parent={animal}}
@index{goose,plural={geese},parent={animal}}

@entry{sample,
  name={sample},
  description={an example with a description}
}

@abbreviation{html,
  short="html",
  long={hypertext markup language}
}

@symbol{pi,
  name={\ensuremath{\pi}}
}
```

Here's an example document that only uses one term from the `entries.bib` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={entries}% data in entries.bib
]

\begin{document}
\gls{sample}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

The `testidx-glossaries` package provides support for `bib2gls`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[bib2gls]{testidx-glossaries}

\tstidxmakegloss

\begin{document}
\testidx

\printunsrtglossary[title={Index}]
\end{document}
```

`\tstidxmakegloss` is a convenient shortcut that does `\makenoidxglossaries` or `\makeglossaries` or `\GlsXtrLoadResources` depending on the package options. In this case it actually performs several `\GlsXtrLoadResource` calls. These can be found in the `.log` file if you add the `verbose` package option. Here is an example with explicit calls:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[bib2gls,manual]{testidx-glossaries}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testidx-glossaries-mathsym},
 group={Maths},
 sort={letter-case},
 selection={recorded and deps and see},
 ignore-fields={description}
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testidx-glossaries-markers},
 group={Markers},
 sort={letter-case},
 selection={recorded and deps and see},
 ignore-fields={description}
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testidx-glossaries-numbers},
 sort={integer},
 selection={recorded and deps and see},
 ignore-fields={description}]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={\tstidxbasebibfiles,\tstidxutfbibfiles,\tstidxglyphfile-utf8},
 selection={recorded and deps and see},
 ignore-fields={description}]

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}

\begin{document}
\testidx

\printunsrtglossary[title={Index}]
\end{document}
```

Each instance of `\GlsXtrLoadResources` creates a new block in the index/glossary (which may be identified by the `type` option, but in this example there's only the default `main` type). A block doesn't necessarily correspond to a letter group or provide any visual distinction. It just allows different sorting within one list. The `group` option assigns the letter group if required, but `bib2gls` must be called with the `--group` (or `-g`) switch to work with this option. The value of the group option is a label. If the corresponding title is different, it can be set with `\glsxtrsetgrouptitle`.

> Handling numbers

Numbers can be sorted using one of the number sort methods. In the above, the third block is sorted according to `sort={integer}`. Java recognises various number systems, so as long as the sort values can be parsed they should be numerically sorted. Any values that can't be parsed will be treated as 0.

> Setting up a new set of sorting rules and letter groups

Custom groups (such as numbers and symbols) can be created as shown above, but you can also supply your own rule. The rule syntax can be quite long, but the `glossaries-extra-bib2gls` package (which is automatically loaded by `glossaries-extra` when the `record` option is used) provides some convenient shortcuts. For example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[bib2gls,manual]{testidx-glossaries}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testidx-glossaries-mathsym},
 group={Maths},
 sort={letter-case},
 selection={recorded and deps and see},
 ignore-fields={description}
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testidx-glossaries-markers},
 group={Markers},
 sort={letter-case},
 selection={recorded and deps and see},
 ignore-fields={description}
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testidx-glossaries-numbers},
 sort={integer},
 selection={recorded and deps and see},
 ignore-fields={description}]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={\tstidxbasebibfiles,\tstidxutfbibfiles,\tstidxglyphfile-utf8},
 selection={recorded and deps and see},
 ignore-fields={description},
 sort={custom},
 sort-rule={\glsxtrcontrolrules
  ;\glsxtrspacerules
  ;\glsxtrnonprintablerules
  ;\glsxtrcombiningdiacriticrules
  ,\glsxtrhyphenrules
  <\glsxtrgeneralpuncrules
  <\glsxtrdigitrules
  <\glsxtrfractionrules
  <a,A <b,B <c,C <ch,CH,Ch <d,D <dd,DD,Dd <e,E <f,F <ff,FF <g,G <ng,NG,Ng
  <h,H <i,I <l,L <ll,LL <m,M <n,N <o,O <p,P <ph,PH,ph <r,R <s,S <t,T
  <th,TH,Th <u,U <w,W <y,Y
 }
]

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}

\begin{document}
\testidx

\printunsrtglossary[title={Index}]
\end{document}
```

> Modifying rules

This can also be done through a custom rule. If you run `bib2gls` with the `--debug` switch, the rule will be written to the transcript `.glg` file. (Search for `Collator rules:`) You can copy and paste this, but be careful of the control codes at the start. It's best to replace them with `\glsxtrcontrolrules` etc as shown above.

> Support for indexing more languages in one index

You can either use a custom rule that supports both languages or use a separate `\GlsXtrLoadResources` for each language. For example:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={german-terms},sort={de-CH-1996}]
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={japanese-terms},sort={ja}]
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={sanskrit-terms},sort={sa}]
```

> Two-way hyperlinks

The terms are referenced in the document using commands like `\gls` provided by the `glossaries` package. These become hyperlinks to the relevant entry in the list if the `hyperref` package is loaded before `glossaries` (and therefore before `glossaries-extra` and `testidx-glossaries`, which implicitly load it).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[bib2gls]{testidx-glossaries}

\tstidxmakegloss

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}

\begin{document}
\testidx

\printunsrtglossary[title={Index}]
\end{document}
```

The page numbers in the location lists link back. If you want the term to link back (for example, to the primary reference), then it's more complicated but can be done, although it's still experimental. (Requires at least `glossaries-extra` v1.29 and `bib2gls` v1.4.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record,indexcounter]{glossaries-extra}

\newcommand{\primary}[1]{\hyperbf{#1}}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={test-entries},
 save-index-counter=primary
]

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\GlsXtrIndexCounterLink{#1}{\glscurrententrylabel}}

\begin{document}

A \gls{sample}. \lipsum*[1] A \gls{duck}.

An equation:
\begin{equation}
\gls[counter=equation]{pi}
\end{equation}
And some more equations:
\begin{align}
A &= b\\
f(x) &= \gls[counter=equation]{pi}x
\end{align}

\lipsum[2]

Another \gls[format=primary]{sample}. \lipsum*[3] Another \gls{duck}.

\gls{pi}. \lipsum[4]

A \gls{sample}. \lipsum*[5] A \gls{duck} and \gls[format=primary]{pi}.

\lipsum*[6] A \gls[format=primary]{duck}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

> Index with different piece of information

You can use a different counter for the location using the `counter` option (for example, `\gls[counter=equation]{pi}` in the above example) or you can use a custom location for example:

```
\glsadd[thevalue={Supplementary Material}]{sample}
```

By default the locations are in the same order that they were indexed, but you can separate the locations according to the `counter` used when indexing. For example:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
loc-counters={equation,page},% group locations by counter
src={entries}% data in entries.bib
]
```

You can provide additional information in other fields. (See the "Examples" chapter in the `bib2gls` manual.)

> Easy setting of the tags at the output side

This can be done through the glossary style or using the hooks provided by `glossaries-extra`. Again, see the "Examples" chapter in the `bib2gls` user manual.

> Mixing writing

Similarly you can provide one field for one script and another field for another script. You can use `\glsaddkey` provided by the base `glossaries` package to define the field and provide some user commands to reference the field in the document. The `@dualentry` entry `.bib` format can provide a way of indexing both forms (as two separate terms, optionally in different index/glossary lists).

> Sorting engine off, indexing engine on

You can switch off sorting with `sort=none`, but this can cause a problem for hierarchical entries so I've used `flatten` in the example below to remove the hierarchy:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[bib2gls,manual]{testidx-glossaries}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={testidx-glossaries-mathsym,
  testidx-glossaries-markers,
  testidx-glossaries-numbers,
  \tstidxbasebibfiles,\tstidxutfbibfiles,\tstidxglyphfile-utf8},
 selection={recorded and deps and see},
 ignore-fields={description},
 flatten,
 sort={none}
]

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}

\begin{document}
\testidx

\printunsrtglossary[title={Index}]
\end{document}
```

This will list the entries in order of definition (in the `.bib` files). You can also use `sort=use` to list in order of first use in the document or `sort=random` for a random list.

> Sorting engine on, indexing engine off

You can select all defined entries (regardless of whether they've been referenced in the document) using `selection=all`. (If any have been indexed in the document, you can use `save-locations=false` to omit the location lists.)

Related reading:

- Testing indexes: testidx.sty. [TUGboat 38:3, 2017](http://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents38-3.html).
- [`bib2gls` user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org//support/bib2gls/bib2gls.pdf)